# How to call a script 2 along with its 2 parameters from script 1 without making any changes to script 1?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 scripts.

1) `script1.sh` -> it does nothing but calls the `script2.sh` and keeps the log and time etc. I cannot make any changes to script1.sh. Its just used for calling `script2.sh`

2) `script2.sh` -> Its only a command that loads one file from a particular location to another location. I am passing the filename from location 1 as parameter 1 and filename where it is uploaded to location 2 as parameter 2.

script2.sh :

```
file1=$1
file2=$2

/home/test put /home/$1 uploads/final/$2
```

The final script that i run is :

```
script1.sh script2.sh file1=abc.csv file2=xyz.csv
```

But somehow i cannot use the parameters of the called script 2. Is there a way i can use the parameters of the called script 2 without changing the script 1.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide the full text of script1.sh? It is the gating item and will dictate what script2.sh should contain. At a guess, script1 only uses `$1` but ignores its own `$2` and `$3`, so it can _not_ pass them to script2. If you can also post script2, that would help as well

Comment: script1.sh is nothing but a huge file taking care of logs, will send an email if it fails etc. The only thing it does is it calls script2.sh.  I can run the script2.sh independently but i want all the logs and other functionality of script1.sh. So i need to use script1.sh without changing it. I have already posted my content of script2.sh

Comment: Post the actual line that script1 uses to invoke script2. That should be sufficient [and necessary]

Comment: Unfortunately i donot have the access to the script1.sh but it takes in 2 parameters. script1.sh param1 param2. The parameters are optional. I can

Comment: when you print $1 , $2 in side script2.sh, what is getting printed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for `script2.sh` to access the arguments that were given to `script1.sh`. If `script1.sh` doesn't pass arguments to `script2.sh`, you can use environment variables instead.

```
file1=abc.csv file2=xyz.csv script1.sh script2.sh
```

This sets the environment variables `file1` and `file2` while invoking `script1.sh`. Unless `script1.sh` takes deliberate action to overwrite them, they'll be passed on to `script2.sh` automatically.

You can then remove the lines in `script2.sh` that assign to `file1` and `file2`. They will already be set in the environment.

Comment: script1.sh makes use of one argument in which it calls script2.sh. But script2.sh has two arguments which does not get implemented.

Comment: Anything that `script1.sh` doesn't pass itself can be passed as an environment variable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Like minds think alike. As Barmar said, use environment variables:

Create a launcher script:

```
#!/bin/sh -

export SCRIPT2_A1=$1
export SCRIPT2_A2=$2

script1.sh script2.sh
```

Now change script2.sh to look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

A1=${SCRIPT2_A1:-$1}
A2=${SCRIPT2_A2:-$2}

# now use A1 and A2 as you would $1 and $2
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$ script1.sh "script2.sh file1=abc.csv file2=xyz.csv"`

That is add double quotes

Comment: It depends on how `script1.sh` uses its argument when running the given command.

Comment: @Barmar, But the OP has to say.

Comment: @Barmar, You are perfect, but just I am trying to find a possible work around for the OP. There is a fair chance that my idea may click well. Let us see what he says.

Comment: @JayKumarR Instead of blindly firing an answer, you should request clarification from the OP by commenting on his question.

Comment: @Austin, did you check if the above solution works for you?